# CGFloat Incompatible types in initialization

Tags: objective-c, cgfloat

Anyone see the issue here?

```
double latDouble = [latString doubleValue];
double lngDouble = [lngString doubleValue];

CGFloat dist = [self calcDiffDistance:latDouble withPostLng:lngDouble]; // Incompatible types in initialization

- (float)calcDiffDistance:(double)postLat withPostLng:(double)lon1
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `typedef` for `CGFloat` is `double` on a 64-bit system, and `float` on a 32-bit system. My guess is you're compiling on a 64-bit system, and are assigning a `float` return value to a `double` variable.